# I cannot assign a primary key or a foreign key in mysqldb, with python.

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using MySQLdb in python, and I cannot get it to create a table with a primary or foreign key. I can create a table, since the following works:

```
theconn = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'pw', 'db')
theDB = theconn.cursor();
theDB.execute("CREATE TABLE hf_aum_returns ( \
    FundID INT NOT NULL , \
    Metric_Type CHAR(10) , \
    Metric_Value FLOAT , \
    DateTime DATE )")
```

However, when I run the following line:

```
theDB.execute("CREATE TABLE hf_aum_returns_2 ( \
    FundID INT NOT NULL , \
    Metric_Type CHAR(10) , \
    Metric_Value FLOAT , \
    DateTime DATE , \
    CONSTRAINT returns_pk PRIMARY KEY ( FundID , Metric_Type , Metric_Value , DateTime )")
```

I get an error telling me to check my syntax:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
```

Comment: Is that ( F supposed to be at the end of your code block? Looks like you meant to do ) ?

Comment: Just as a tip to improve readability you can triple quote SQL statements and not use the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. I am not bright. Missed a parenthesis, at the end of the statement. (...been staring at it for an hour...)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis:

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE hf_aum_returns_2 ( FundID INT NOT NULL , Metric_Type CHAR(10) , Metric_Value FLOAT , DateTime DATE , CONSTRAINT returns_pk PRIMARY KEY (FundID,Metric_Type,Metric_Value,DateTime))
```